# htaccess rewrite rule not working for http://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]+)$ page.php?site=$1 [L]
```

It is working fine for

```
http://example.com/site/google.com
```

But not working when i add **http://** or **https://** before google.com like

```
http://example.com/site/http://google.com
```

OR

```
http://example.com/site/https://google.com
```

Please share a rewrite rule which can accept everything after **/site/** like **http://example.com/site/here_it_may_be_any**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture `http://` type string from `RewriteCond` otherwise Apache strips multiple slash to single in `RewriteRule` pattern. Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I am doing this in localhost. My link is **directory of project /site/http://google.com** and i am getting 404 error. There is a problem in stackoverflow. I add http:// before google.com

Comment: Where is this htaccess located and where is `page.php` located?

Comment: This is working **RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ page.php?site=$1 [L]** but Apache strips multiple slash to single.

Comment: htaccess file and page both are in same directory.

Comment: I think your rule is not in `DocumentRoot`. Try my updated rule now.